# Simple form change dom output for association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I am using a theme for my website and I am trying to have something like that (not perfect it is how the theme works...):

```
<div class="input-checkbox input-checkbox--switch">
  <input name="agree" type="checkbox">/</input>
  <label for="checkbox-switch"></label>
</div>
<span>Helper text for checkbox</span>
```

Currently, I am using simple form like that

```
= simple_form_for current_user.shop do |f|
  = f.error_notification
  = f.association :services, collection: Service.active.order(:name), as: :check_boxes
```

And the output is:

```
<div class="input-checkbox input-checkbox--switch">
  <input class="form-check-input check_boxes optional" type="checkbox" value="7" name="shop[service_ids][]" id="shop_service_ids_7">
  <label class="form-check-label collection_check_boxes" for="shop_service_ids_7">Service 1</label>
</div>
```

So I need to put the text label after the global wrapper into a span tag and remove the text from the `<label>` tag.

I tried a lot of things but I am lost with the wrapper, inputs, builders of simple_form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspired from Max's answer:

```
= f.collection_check_boxes :service_ids, @services, :id, :name do |b|
  .input-checkbox.input-checkbox--switch
    = b.check_box
    = label_tag b, '', { for: "shop_service_ids_#{b.value}" }
   %span= b.text
```

Answer (score 1):

If you **really** had to generate that markup you can do it by using Rails built in `collection_checkboxes` helper.

```
= f.collection_checkboxes :service_ids, @services, :id, :name do |b|
  = f.input :services # adds the simple form wrapper  
    = b.label ""
    = b.check_box
  span b.text
```

But I would really just fix the theme instead as this creates a huge accesibilty problem as screenreaders won't be able to read the label, you won't be able to target the label text with Capybara in your acceptance tests and it feels like a ridiculous solution to what is presumeably a simple CSS or JS problem.

See [Wrapping Rails Form Helpers](https://github.com/heartcombo/simple_form#wrapping-rails-form-helpers).